# ThinkPad Yoga distorting/compressing some icons

Tags: display, thinkpad, graphics

I have a brand new TP Yoga Pro with W8.1 Pro x64 that *intermittently* distorts some icons and other graphics seemingly at random. I notice it most with icons on the task bar or system tray, but it also happens in Windows dialogs and to other things like the tabs in FireFox.

The distortion basically looks like it compressed them to about half their native quality, and for what it's worth it carries over to an external monitor so I know it's probably not hardware-related.

I have applied every single update available in Windows and from Lenovo's website, which appeared to make the problem go away for a few days but now it's back so that may have been a coincidence. I've searched around and can't find anyone else experiencing this issue (including my coworker who has the exact same laptop), though I don't exactly know how to describe it to a search engine so I may have missed something.

Has anyone else seen this kind of behavior or know of a lead to a solution?

Here's an example of a distorted icon followed by what it's supposed to look like normally (taken from another machine):

[image: Bad Spotify]

[image: Good Spotify]

**Edit:** Forgot to mention, only *some* icons are distorted at any given time (usually 1-3), the rest appear fine.

Here's an additional example of the problem happening with a default system icon, as opposed to an icon from an installed application:

[image: Bad Dialog]

Comment: Where's that icon being displayed?  Are you pinching or shift-wheel on the desktop, thus affecting the zoom of the desktop icons?

Comment: What's your screen resolution? And what's the screen resolution of your coworkers?

Comment: Both resolutions are set at 1920x1080. The desktop is not zoomed in any way. I should have mentioned the rest of the icons look perfectly fine, there are only some that are distorted at any given time. And both those icons are from the task bar

Comment: So I'm confused . . . if both desktops are at 1920x1080, and there's no zooming, why are the icons different sizes?  The top one is about 1/3 larger than the bottom one . . .

Comment: It was taken from another machine that does not suffer the distortion (for comparison purposes)

Comment: Ah I think I see your confusion, I was answering @ThatBrazilianGuy when I said "Both resolutions are set at 1920x1080"